# ControlSend sends incorrect text to background app

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I am trying to send a URL to a background app. I have tried the following:

```
url = https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=autohotkey+send+url
ControlSendRaw, , %url%, Mozilla Firefox

url= {Raw}https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=autohotkey+send+url
ControlSend, , %url%, Mozilla Firefox

url := "https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=autohotkey+send+url"
ControlSendRaw, , %url%, Mozilla Firefox

//output: https;//www.google.nl//gws-rd=ssl3q=autohotkey=send=url
```

The output keeps coming out wrong, with symbols like `:` being mistyped as `;`

I would rather not modify the string itself otherwise I have to automate that process too since I get those dynamically.

Is there a way to output a string with it's exact characters?

Comment: The first command sends the text correctly here on AHK 1.1.21.03

Comment: I confirmed that in version 1.1.22.07 ControlSend does indeed garble up the string that is sent to Firefox. If I were you, I'd drop using any attempt at automating Firefox and switch it up to IE COM. It's really the best choice for web browser automation in Ahk. Alternatively you can bring the browser in focus and use a traditional Send, %YourVariable% as this does work correctly.

Comment: @ahkcoder Do you think this was a bug introduced in newer versions of AHK?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Do you think you can take some time to accept answers to some questions you have asked? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432447/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-an-autohotkey-array/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) has a known reliability issue where the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key isn't always held down. This means that capital letters or special symbols aren't always typed correctly. (see *[ControlSend gets upper/lower case wrong?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/2215-controlsend-gets-upperlower-case-wrong/)*)

Note that the mistyped symbols in your URL required holding down shift. (`:`, `?`, `_`, `#`, `+`)

### Option 1: Set a [KeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm)

```
SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
ControlSend, , %url%, Mozilla Firefox
```

Setting a key delay with [`SetKeyDelay`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) should improve the reliability of sent keystrokes. I've found that a delay of 5 or 10 is usually enough to fix any capitalization issues.

### Option 2: Use [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) or [SendInput](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail)

```
WinActivate, Mozilla Firefox
SendInput, %url%
```

If you want to send input to an app which isn't in the background, I recommend bringing your window into focus with [`WinActivate`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) and using [`Send`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) or [`SendInput`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail). These commands are generally more reliable for sending input.

Answer (score 1):

You showed what you tried, but what were the results?
I can only assume that some characters were missing and in that case

```
SetKeyDelay 10, 10
```

would probably help.