# How do I remove duplicates from an AutoHotkey array?

Tags: arrays, duplicates, autohotkey

I have an [array](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm) of strings in AutoHotkey which contains duplicate entries.

```
nameArray := ["Chris","Joe","Marcy","Chris","Elina","Timothy","Joe"]
```

I would like to remove any duplicates so that only unique values remain.

```
trimmedArray := ["Chris","Joe","Marcy","Elina","Timothy"]
```

Ideally I'm looking for a function similar to [Trim()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Trim.htm) which would return a trimmed array while leaving the original array intact. (i.e. `trimmedArray := RemoveDuplicates(nameArray)`)

**How do I remove duplicates from my AutoHotkey array?**

Comment: Anyone reading the code should be able to determine it's purpose deduce that a single iteration over the the initial array is going to be faster than two, as the other examples demostrate. I added an alternative for you to test, I'd suggest using a large data set and comparing computation times in Miliseconds. I'm not sure that the built in haskey method doesn't add additional cost, a simple check for a value may prove to be slighty faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaves the original intact, only loops once, preserves order:

```
nameArray := ["Chris","Joe","Marcy","Chris","Elina","Timothy","Joe"]

trimmedArray := trimArray(nameArray)

trimArray(arr) { ; Hash O(n) 

    hash := {}, newArr := []

    for e, v in arr
        if (!hash.Haskey(v))
            hash[(v)] := 1, newArr.push(v)

    return newArr
}
```

An alternative to using the haskey method, would be to check a value in our hash object. This may prove to be more efficient and faster, but I'll leave the testing to you.

```
trimArray(arr) { ; Hash O(n) 

    hash := {}, newArr := []

    for e, v in arr
        if (!hash[v])
            hash[(v)] := 1, newArr.push(v)

    return newArr
}
```

Edit: Initially I wasn't going to test, but I got curious as well as tired of waiting on the OP. The results don't surprise me much:

[image]

What we are seeing here is the average execution times for 10,000 tests, the lower the number, the faster the task was computed. The clear winner is my script variation without Haskey Method, but only by tiny margin! All in the other methods were doomed, being that they are not linear solutions.

Test Code is here:

```
setbatchlines -1 

tests := {test1:[], test2:[], test3:[], test4:[]}

Loop % 10000 {
    nameArray := ["Chris","Joe","Marcy","Chris","Elina","Timothy","Joe"]

    QPC(1)

    jimU(nameArray)

    test1 := QPC(0), QPC(1)

    AbdullaNilam(nameArray)

    test2 := QPC(0), QPC(1)

    ahkcoderVer1(nameArray)

    test3 := QPC(0), QPC(1)

    ahkcoderVer2(nameArray)

    test4 := QPC(0)

    tests["test1"].push(test1), tests["test2"].push(test2)
    , tests["test3"].push(test3), tests["test4"].push(test4)
}

scripts := ["Jim U         ", "Abdulla Nilam  "
            , "ahkcoder HasKey", "ahkcoder Bool  " ]

for e, testNums in tests ; Averages Results
    r .= "Test Script " scripts[A_index] "`t:`t" sum(testNums) / 10000 "`n"


msgbox % r

AbdullaNilam(names) {

    for i, namearray in names
        for j, inner_namearray in names
            if (A_Index > i && namearray = inner_namearray)
                names.Remove(A_Index)
    return names
}

JimU(nameArray) {
  hash := {}
  for i, name in nameArray
    hash[name] := null

  trimmedArray := []
  for name, dummy in hash
    trimmedArray.Insert(name)

  return trimmedArray
}

ahkcoderVer1(arr) { ; Hash O(n) - Linear

    hash := {}, newArr := []

    for e, v in arr
        if (!hash.Haskey(v))
            hash[(v)] := 1, newArr.push(v)

    return newArr
}

ahkcoderVer2(arr) { ; Hash O(n) - Linear

    hash := {}, newArr := []

    for e, v in arr
        if (!hash[v])
            hash[(v)] := 1, newArr.push(v)

    return newArr
}

sum(arr) {
    r := 0
    for e, v in arr
        r += v
    return r
}

QPC(R := 0) ; https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6413
{
    static P := 0, F := 0, Q := DllCall("QueryPerformanceFrequency", "Int64P", F)
    return ! DllCall("QueryPerformanceCounter", "Int64P", Q) + (R ? (P := Q) / F : (Q - P) / F) 
}
```

Comment: Nice test!  Thanks for sharing it. While your variations are clearly more efficient, I believe our algorithms share the same complexity: O(n) when operating on an average data set.  My extra step of traversing a hash should be O(n) and adds no complexity. Yes?

Comment: Its been awhile since my Big O studies, but i believe each iteration through a data structure adds to complexity ie time, which is why in the test, your algo was slower. I have to say, you were so close to nailing a perfect solution, kinda why I jumped in here and posted my solution.

Comment: I already upvoted this answer a long ago (thanks!), but could you explain how you use `hash[(v)] := 1`? Is it really `1` or may be it is assumed to be `True`?

Answer (score 2):

**Generates an array containing only the unique elements of another array**

```
uniq(nameArray)
{
  hash := {}
  for i, name in nameArray
    hash[name] := null

  trimmedArray := []
  for name, dummy in hash
    trimmedArray.Insert(name)

  return trimmedArray
}
```

This code uses an associative array to eliminate duplicates. Because it uses a keyed lookup, it should perform better on large arrays than using nested loops, which is *O(n²)*

**Test**

```
for i, name in uniq(["Chris","Joe","Marcy","Chris","Elina","Timothy","Joe"])
  s := s . ", " . name

MsgBox % substr(s, 3)
```

**Output**

[image]

Note that the order of the elements in the first array is not preserved

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
names := ["Chris","Joe","Marcy","Chris","Elina","Timothy","Joe"]

for i, namearray in names
    for j, inner_namearray in names
        if (A_Index > i && namearray = inner_namearray)
            names.Remove(A_Index)
```

[Check this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/68613-add-variables-to-array-and-check-for-duplicates/)

Comment: Is there a method which would leave the original untrimmed array in-tact? (Similar to how [trim()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Trim.htm) works)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro You can [clone](https://autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Clone_AHK_L_60+) it before processing.